# (Product Search API) - No matching products - Caused by index issue?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vision, google-product-search

I'm using the Product Search API, and I'm having an issue with finding products.

I have a product with reference images and when I do a search of any of the images I uploaded or similar it returns 'No matching products found'.

> I have waited over 30 minutes for the index to update

However, when I list the product set it is inside I noticed the product set indexTime is set to a 0 timestamp?

Is this the cause and how do I find out why it is set to this?

Product set dump:

```
{#355
  +"productSets": array:1 [
    0 => {#375
      +"name": "the name here"
      +"displayName": "test"
      +"indexTime": "1970-01-01T00:00:00Z"
      +"indexError": {#349}
    }
  ]
}
```

The index error is an empty array?

Comment: As Indexing is an automatic process that occurs approximately every 30 minutes, this seems like and issue, I recommend to create an issue in the public Issue Tracker. https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker/

Answer (score 1):

The indexing is automatic. Since your set has a 0 timestamp, your set hasn't been indexed yet. One thing you could do is verify that you have added the products to the product set by listing the products in the product set. If a set has no products with images, it won't be indexed.